# Inject JavaScript file/script into another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-injection

**Scenario**: I am creating a page containing a  list of 150+ imgs (each categorized with classes). I am not able to modify this page directly. Therefore, I need to inject a script from an active page I do have control of (containing questions/selections). This is then intended to hide/show relevant imgs with a simple jQuery script, depending on the selections on this active page.

**Q**: Is it possible to inject a .js script or function from one source into another HTML page, which in this case will show/hide relevant images?

***Background***: *I am restricted to client-side scripting only. I am also not in a position to add a variable to the URL and query this as I first thought. Apologies if this question is not clear, I've found it difficult to summarise but please comment with any queries.*

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be possible, surely it poses a security risk?

Comment: Could you further explain this: _"I am creating a page containing a list of 150+ imgs (each categorized with classes). I am not able to modify this page directly"_ how can you create a page if you cant modify it directly? If you are actually creating this page, why are you not adding the JS as per normal? This sounds like a dubious request of yours.. MITM attacks spring to mind...

Comment: I now realise it looks suspicious! I should clarify, it's a static page which I need to modify dynamically from another page. So I create it, can control it, can edit it, but not dynamically - this has to be done from another source. To be specific, it's a page that users will be given a link to from a survey, and dependant on their info in the survey, it needs to show specific images. Its to try and save creating 60+ HTML pages with the right logo set ups